# Wordpress Event calendar + timeline plugin?

Tags: wordpress

Are there any paid or free plugins out there that supports an event calendar and timeline display of said calendar?

Currently using Event Calendar by Modern Tribe and Timeline Express for timelines so I have to duplicate two entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin looks good:
https://codecanyon.net/item/timetable-for-wordpress/1264400?ref=pxcr
Offers a TV channel / programme listings like timeline with date picker in top left and timeline beneath it.